# Files disappearing, errors during linux boot

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, smart

On my laptop I've got - Windows 7 (NTFS), Ubuntu 10.10 x64 (ext4) and a few NTFS partitions which are also mounted under Ubuntu.

1.Today when I opened console text like this appeared: "I don't know you". In Users and groups there was nothing! No users, no groups! I've rebooted PC and then it could not boot - error while mounting filesystem and cannot open password database. I've booted from Live cd, /etc/password was corrupted so I've used /etc/password- file. Linux booted successfully. On ntfs partition I've found strange files: fileX.ntfs-3g-0000000002 fileX.ntfs-3g-0000000003 ... ntfs-3g-0000000154.

2. While ago after work under linux, when I booted into Windows appeared screen with disk error checking - after scanning some files from the disk disappeared.
3. I've checked disk with a few S.M.A.R.T. checking tools - everything seems to be OK. Tool from BIOS (ThinkPad) for checking disk and disk controller found no errors.
4. While booting Ubuntu after hibernation appears errors (but it still boots):

   [image]

Comment: You have either a disk error (failing hard disk, loose cable, …) or bad RAM (which could explain that render error as well). Try running memtest overnight (from the Grub boot menu). Look for disk-related errors under `/var/log/kern.log` (or maybe `/var/log/kern.log.0` and so on for older messages), if the files have survived.

Comment: After 3:31:01 Memtest hang (after 3 passes, no errors, but it does not respond...).

Comment: Haven't seen anything like that, ever. Perhaps some part of your machine is overheating, and memtest's stress stops it dead?

Comment: Did you happen to edit any of the system's file while it was hibernated? Let's say - you put Windows in hibernation, boot Ubuntu and edited some files which belong to Windows while it was hibernated or vice versa. Did you?

Comment: Interesting, 4 year old question and comments suddenly appear. @Nikolay as far as I remember Windows didnt even see the linux since linux was on ext or sth like that! When I stopped do the hibernation when changing the OS problems disappeared.

Comment: @mmatloka, Yeah, I noticed age of the question after posting comment. Chenmunka edited question and it got to the main site's page where I picked it up... Anyway, I have read some posts on Super User about people editing Windows files while Windows was in hibernation. Later there were many problems because of that.